# what is wrong with this c++ linked list code?

Tags: c++

Iam working on C++ console application course

I was trying to creat a linked list

and the visual studio just gived me like over 30 Errors though the code seems perfectly fine to me

**What is thye actual error ?**
[image]

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class Nodetype>
class Node{
private:
    Nodetype data;
    Node<Nodetype>*next;
    friend Linkedlist ;
};

template <class Nodetype>
class Linkedlist{
private:
    Node<Nodetype>*head;
public:
    Linkedlist();
    void insertItem(Nodetype item);
    void DeleteItem(Nodetype item);
    void MakeEmpty();
    bool FindItem(Nodetype item);
    void Display();
};
template <class Nodetype>
Linkedlist<Nodetype>::Linkedlist()
{
    head = NULL;
}

template <class Nodetype>
void Linkedlist< Nodetype >::insertItem(Nodetype item)
{
    Node< Nodetype > *location;
    location = new Node< Nodetype >();
    location->data = item;
    location->next = head;
    head = location;
}

template <class Nodetype>
void Linkedlist<Nodetype>::Display()
{
    Node<Nodetype>*current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        cout << current->data;
        current = current->next;
    }
}

template <class Nodetype>
void Linkedlist< Nodetype >::DeleteItem(Nodetype item)
{
    Node< Nodetype >* preLocation = NULL;
    Node< Nodetype >* location = head;
    if (item == location->data)
        head = location->next;
    else
    {
        do
        {
            preLocation = location;
            location = location->next;
        } while (item != location->data);
        preLocation->next = location->next;
    }
    delete location;
}

template <class Nodetype>
void Linkedlist<Nodetype>::MakeEmpty()
{
    Node<Nodetype>* tempPtr;
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        tempPtr = head;
        head = head > next;
        delete tempPtr;
    }
}

template <class Nodetype>
bool Linkedlist<Nodetype>::FindItem(Nodetype item)
{
    bool found;
    Node<Nodetype> *currentPos = head;
    found = false;
    while ((currentPos != NULL) && !found)
    {
        if (item == (currentPos->data))
            found = true;
        else
            currentPos = currentPos->next;
    }
    return found;
}

void main(){
    int x = 0;
    Linkedlist<string> L;
    L.insertItem("name1");
    L.insertItem("name2");


    cin >> x;
}
```

Comment: Just go debug it. I'm sure you can find plenty of error messages on the side.

Comment: "the code seems perfectly fine, I'm sure these compiler errors mean nothing".

Comment: _"the code seems perfectly fine to me"_ - General rule of thumb, every time you think the compiler is wrong you are.

Comment: I know thats way Iam saying "to me" it means I cant see what is the problem not that Iam accuseing the compiler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> and the visual studio just gived me like over 30 Errors though the code seems perfectly fine to me

It's not fine, it's full of errors.

Listen to your compiler. Go to the lines it tells you have errors. Fix them.

For example:

```
     head = head > next;
```

That's clearly wrong. Fix it.

And this isn't valid C++:

```
friend Linkedlist ;
```

it should be:

```
template<class T> friend class LinkedList;
```

but you should declare `LinkedList` first, before you say it's a friend.

Comment: fixed "head = head > next;" nothing changed :D but when declared LinkedList first the errors went from 30 : 3  i think i can deal with the rest  thnak you for pointing that :)

Comment: ps: "friend Linkedlist ;" acutlly works fine with me